# Python 3 - A simple text string from user input to hex

Tags: python, python-3.3

I want my code to accept user input then convert it to Hex

```
hex_name = input("Would you like to convert to hex?,Type Yes or No: ")


if hex_name == 'Yes' or hex_name == 'yes' or hex_name == 'YES':
        hex_input = input("Enter String value here:")
        h_input = binascii.hexlify(b'hex_input')
        print(hex_input, "Converts to: ", h_input)

        #when user enters no
elif hex_name == 'No' or hex_name == 'no' or hex_name == 'NO':
    print("You said", hex_name, "have a nice day!")

    #when user enters an empty space or hits the enter-bar
elif hex_name == '' or hex_name == ' ' or hex_name == '  ':
    print("Empty value detected, please try again")

#Ends program if user enters anything than a yes or no
elif  hex_name != 'Yes' or hex_name != 'yes':
        print("Sorry", hex_name, "is not a valid input")
        print("Please enter Yes or No, ", "have a nice day!")
```

'''The code works but it prints the hex value of hex_input instead of the user input, What am i doing wrong?'''

I am all very new to python and i use python 3.3.2

Comment: Can you give an example of the input you want to give and the output you expect for it?

Comment: consider testing `hex_name` by converting to lower, e.g. `if hex_name.lower() == 'yes':` to avoid iffy case conditions -- off topic but useful info

Comment: It doesn't really matter here, but note that `hex_name != 'Yes' or hex_name != 'yes'` always evaluates to True. Use [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) when negating a boolean expression.

Comment: You have passed a string hexlify ! Pass it the variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `hex_input`:

```
binascii.hexlify(bytes(hex_input))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're specifically passing the string "hex_input", not the variable hex_input. That's why it's giving you the hex value of the string "hex_input".

You have to remove the quotes around "hex_input":

```
if hex_name == 'Yes' or hex_name == 'yes' or hex_name == 'YES':
        hex_input = input("Enter String value here:")
        h_input = binascii.hexlify(b'hex_input')
                                    ^         ^
                                these need to be removed
```

So the line should be:

```
h_input = binascii.hexlify(bytes(hex_input))
```

If you put quotes around something Python is going to look at whatever is between the quotes as a string. The value of `hex_input` is already a string, therefore you can just pass `hex_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes around hex_input and you're good to go.

Since you're pretty new to python, be aware that you can easily improve the quality and readability of your code. Following is just the start of it !

```
hex_name = input("Would you like to convert to hex?,Type Yes or No: ")
hex_name = hex_name.strip().lower()

if hex_name:
    if hex_name not in ["yes", "no"]:
        print("Sorry", hex_name, "is not a valid input")
        print("Please enter Yes or No, ", "have a nice day!")
    elif hex_name == "yes":
        hex_input = input("Enter String value here:")
        h_input = binascii.hexlify(bytes(hex_input))
        print(hex_input, "Converts to: ", h_input)
    elif hex_name == "no":
        print("You said", hex_name, "have a nice day!")
else:
    print("Empty value detected, please try again")
```